# How do I check user logged input against Parse database

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am quite a newbie to Android programming and i have reached a hurdle in my development. I am learning how to parse information from a database but got stuck in the process. I am trying to find if a username exist in the database i start a new intent, if it does not exist I want to toast some message *does not exist* All of this is done after the user clicks the button "login" but my login button does not do anything. Infact when i try to assign some method to the button"using onlick" only two methods are shown. *setContentView* & *setListFooter* I need some guidance with this problem can anyone assist me?

```
  public class Login extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    final EditText username= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userloginname);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userpassword);


    TextView neighbourView = new TextView(this);

    Button button_test;
    button_test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    button_test.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {

                String usersname = username.getText().toString();
                String passwoord = password.getText().toString();

                ParseObject parkingobject = new ParseObject("Parking");
                parkingobject.put("username",usersname);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "password is : " + passwoord +" Username is  " + usersname + "  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // System.out.println(username + "" + password);
                //Log.i(usersname + usersname, passwoord + passwoord);
                parkingobject.saveInBackground();



                ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                query.whereEqualTo("username", usersname);

                query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (e == null) {
                            if (count == 0) {

                                //Username doesnt exit

                                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                                startActivity(browserIntent);
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user name already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }
                    }

                });

            }
```

and here is my XML

```
     <!--  Username Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="@string/username"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/userloginname"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <!--  Password Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="@string/password"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:password="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/userpassword" />
    <!-- Login button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/loginButton"/>
```

Comment: your class does not extends activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think since you are looking for count, it's better to use your original code with a small modification as below.

```
     ParseObject parkingobject = new ParseObject("Parking");
                    parkingobject.put("username",usersname);
                                 parkingobject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
       public void done(ParseException e) {
         if (e == null) {
             ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                    query.whereEqualTo("username", usersname);

                    query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (e == null) {
                            if (count == 0) {

                                //Username doesnt exit

                                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                                startActivity(browserIntent);
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user name already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
     } else {
       //myObjectSaveDidNotSucceed();
     }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Parking");
        query.whereEqualTo("username", usersname);
         query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> List, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if(List!=null){
                    if(List.size()>0){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user name already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }
                   else{
                      Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                                startActivity(browserIntent);  
                      }
                 }
            } else {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        }
else{
Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());  
}
    });
```

Comment: what is the name of table or class you are querying for?

Comment: I am not asking about the object name, i am asking about the class name, i guess it's Parking, i have updated my answer, please check.

Comment: I get an error at *query.countInBackground(new CountCallback()*

Comment: just updated my answer, i would suggest, you better use this way.

Comment: I am still getting that error with query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() . Forgive me i am new to android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81337/discussion-between-lex-mars-and-aakash).